# Angular: Set default value to <select>

Tags: angular

I have a `<select>` *tag* with input from array like this:

```
<select class="form-control form_cbx long-select" 
        formControlName="category" 
        value="Supplier">
  <option *ngFor="let cat of userCategories" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.name}
  </option>
</select>
```

How do I set the first element of array to be set selected?

Comment: `<option *ngFor="let cat of userCategories" [selected]="cat.name == 'Cat1'" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</option>` See: https://plnkr.co/edit/vBqCr05sSeL3FWO8SJ1z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you put a ng-model object on your select.  Then set a default value to that, it will be selected.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="mySelect">
  <option *ngFor = "let cat of userCategories" [value] = "cat.id">
  {{cat.name}
  </option> 
</select>
```

Then in your controller, just assign this.mySelect=(whatever cat.id you want).

Comment: $scope? This is for Angular 2 and up, I believe.

Comment: The tag says angular.. But if it's angular 2 use **this.mySelect** instead.

Comment: Please, add that to the answer.

Comment: @caden311 the tag in OP is correct. `Angular` refers to Angular 2+. Also, `$scope` and `ng-model` doesn't exists in Angular.

Comment: @developer033 because porting from angularjs to angular 2 is so hard..  I edited just for you bud.

Comment: _"Then set a default value to that, it will be selected."_ this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want is pretty easy... you just need to set the value that you want to set in `category` *control* in the form construction (in this case the first value of your *array*), like this:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  category: this.userCategories[0].id
  // other controls
});
```

**Notes:**

1 - You're missing the second curly brace after `{{cat.name}`, it **must** be `{{cat.name}}`.

2 - Since there's no *value* **attribute** in [**`<select>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), you can just remove it from there.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZ64G6gWUQrfvO1ik0ZO?p=info)